# ListBox not correctly changing ContentControl's ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm still pretty new to WPF and I decided to change the application I am developing to start following the MVVM pattern as best as I could. I am running into a problem when I try to have a list box dictate the view model of a content control. I've been stuck on this for a while and searching the internet is not producing answers for me.

For some reason a new instance of the view model the list box contains is being generated as the data context of the content control. When I was debugging I made sure that the list box contains the view models it should, and that the item I select on the list box is indeed the item that the list box is selecting, however the content control changing based on the selection. There is a view model populating the content control, however it is not in the collection the list box populates from. And I can somehow delete the view model in the content control via my remove button. But when I make a selection change on the list box, or add a new item to the collection it populates the content control with a new view model that once again is not in the collection. I have no clue why it is doing this, or what in my code would suggest this behavior.

I made a simple application to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong. It replicates my problem perfectly. I'm pretty sure the buttons don't adhere to MVVVM (supposed to run a command contained in the view model to adhere to MVVM from what I've been reading) but that is not my main concern right now as the problem exists without the buttons.

MainWindow.xml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="440" Width="436">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:mwvm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ucvm}">
            <local:uc/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="a" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,351,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="r" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,378,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <ContentControl Margin="10,10,110,10" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lb_UCs}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb_UCs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="336" Margin="323,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" ItemsSource="{Binding UCs}" DisplayMemberPath="CoolText"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PanelPartsView : UserControl
{
    private PanelPartsViewModel _DC;

    public PanelPartsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _DC = DataContext as PanelPartsViewModel;
    }

    private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _DC.Panels.Remove(lb_Panels.SelectedItem as PartsViewModel);
    }

    private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pvm = new PartsViewModel();
        _DC.Panels.Add(pvm);
        lb_Panels.SelectedItem = pvm;
        System.Console.WriteLine("lb_Panels.selecteditem = {0}", ((PartsViewModel)lb_Panels.SelectedItem).PanelName);
        System.Console.WriteLine("cc_PanelParts.content = {0}", ((PartsViewModel)cc_PanelParts.Content).PanelName);
    }
}
```

mwvm

```
class mwvm
{
    private ObservableCollection<ucvm> _UCs = new ObservableCollection<ucvm>();

    public ObservableCollection<ucvm> UCs
    {
        get { return _UCs; }
    }

    public mwvm()
    {
        //this is for for testing, the real application would be purely dynamic
        _UCs.Add(new ucvm());
        _UCs.Add(new ucvm());
        _UCs.Add(new ucvm());
    }
}
```

uc.xaml

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.uc" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="90">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ucvm/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Button Content="{Binding CoolText}" Margin="10,10,10,0" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="10,59,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CoolText}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

uc.xaml.cs

```
public partial class uc : UserControl
{
    public uc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ucvm.cs

```
class ucvm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static int i = 1;

    private string _CoolText = "<" + i++ + ">" + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    public string CoolText
    {
        get { return _CoolText; }
        set
        {
            _CoolText = value;
            NPC("CoolText");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NPC(string s)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
    }
}
```

I have also tried binding the content control like so...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedUCVMl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<ListBox x:Name="lb_UCs" ItemsSource="{Binding UCs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUCVM}" DisplayMemberPath="CoolText"/>
```

...and so...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding UCs/}"/>
<ListBox x:Name="lb_UCs" ItemsSource="{Binding UCs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="CoolText"/>
```

but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just have to remove this part from uc.xaml:

```
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ucvm/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
```

This syntax creates a new instance of the view model, each time an instance of uc.xaml is created, which of course isn't what you want.  You want the data context of uc.xaml instances to inherit the instance currently selected in the list box.

Comment: So to make sure I understand what was happening, the data context was being assigned properly at first, and then the InitiallizeComponent() method in the constructor of uc (the view displaying ucvm) was being called and it overwrote the inheritted datacontext as a new instance of ucvm?

Comment: @Orilay yes, exactly.  That snippet of XAML is equivalent to having `this.DataContext = new ucvm()` right after `InitializeComponent()`.